# how to squelch "result not used" warnings

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8

In Swift2.2, I have an extension to `Optional` that looks like:

```
extension Optional {
    func ifNotNil<T>(_ closure:(Wrapped) -> T) -> T? {
        switch self {
        case .some (let wrapped):
            return closure(wrapped)
        case .none:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

It allows for code like

```
anImageView.image = self.something.ifNotNil { self.getImageFor($0) }
```

But sometimes, I don't care about the result:

```
myBSON["key"].string.ifNotNil {
    print($0}
}
```

In Swift2.2, it worked like a charm. But firing up the new XCode8 Beta and converting to Swift3, I'm getting warnings anywhere that I do the second type. It's almost as if there's an implicit `@warn_unused_result`. Is this just an early beta bug? Or something I can no longer do in Swift3? Or something I need to newly fix in Swift3?

Comment: Can't reproduce this issue with Xcode 8.  Can you provide a full, reproducible example which reproduces the issue rather than stub code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can discard the result using:

```
_ = myBSON["key"].string.ifNotNil {
    print($0}
}
```

Or mark your method to not warn for unused results:

```
extension Optional {

    @discardableResult func ifNotNil<T>(_ closure:(Wrapped) -> T) -> T? {
        switch self {
        case .some (let wrapped):
            return closure(wrapped)
        case .none:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Reference : [SE-0047](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0047-nonvoid-warn.md)

Comment: Grumble. I looked for a counterpart to `@warn_unused_result`. Gotta love the symmetry between the two. One uses camelCase, the other under_scores. One is a warn, the other is not.

Comment: In porting, I also have a bunch of other APIs provided by Apple that are apparently not discardable. So anywhere I had something like `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`, I have had to add the `_ = ...` prefix to it. Because apparently the popViewController returns a controller, which I have honestly never needed, and now need to explicitly ignore.

Comment: Yep, it's a little confused right now. But they are moving everything to CamelCase: `Upon acceptance, this proposal removes two of the last remaining instances of snake_case in the Swift language. This further brings the language into a coherent and universal use of lowercase and camel case variants.`

Comment: Yep, I am personal against this Proposal. But I think those API will be annotated with  `@discardableResult` in the future

Comment: I have mixed feelings about `@discardableResult` - while I think it is reasonable (to some extent) there are just too many instances where we really don’t want to deal with the result. As such, `@discardableResult` ends up being “required” noise or we end up with more local variables. In the end I think designers will return nothing rather than add `@discardableResult` - which forces design in a disturbing direction.